# Внесение данных в строки таблицы QTableWidget

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget

День добрый, есть алгоритм который добавляет в `QTableWidget` строку, создавая в нем данные

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(758, 284)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.BT1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.BT1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 301, 71))
        self.BT1.setObjectName("BT1")
        self.BT2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.BT2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 301, 71))
        self.BT2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 30, 361, 151))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.BT1.clicked.connect(self.BT_1_Clicked) # Связь с 1-ой кнопкой
        self.BT2.clicked.connect(self.BT_2_Clicked) # Связь с 2-ой кнопкой

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.BT1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Past 1"))
        self.BT2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Past 2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "x"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "y"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "z"))

    def BT_1_Clicked(self):
        nr = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(nr)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(nr, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('x'))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(nr, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('y'))
        pass

    def BT_2_Clicked(self):
        nr = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(nr)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(nr, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('z'))
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В данном коде при нажатии на кнопку **`№1`** появляется строка, в ней заполняется **`1-ый`** и **`2-ой`** столбец. 
При нажатии на кнопку **`№2`** появляется еще одна строка, и в ней заполняется **`3`** столбец.

Суть задачи: 
Сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку **`№2`** заполнялся **`3-ий`** столбец в строке, которая создалась от **`1-ой`** кнопкой.

Comment: 1.  не рекомендуется злоупотреблять глобальными переменными, как указано в разделе Почему глобальные переменные - зло? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil 2. Если вы хотите получать быстрые и правильные ответы, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick, так понятней?

Answer (score 1):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(758, 284)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.BT1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.BT1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 301, 71))
        self.BT1.setObjectName("BT1")
        
        self.BT2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.BT2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 301, 71))
        self.BT2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 30, 361, 151))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.BT1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Past 1"))
        self.BT2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Past 2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "x"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "y"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "z"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.BT1.clicked.connect(self.bt_1_clicked) 
        self.BT2.clicked.connect(self.bt_2_clicked) 
        
        self.row = None

    def bt_1_clicked(self):
        nr = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        
        if self.row is None:
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(nr)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(nr, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('x'))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(nr, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('y'))
            self.row = nr
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Нарушена последовательность \nнажмите кнопку Past 2') 
 
    def bt_2_clicked(self):
        if not self.row is None:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(self.row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('z'))
            self.row = None
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Нарушена последовательность \nнажмите кнопку Past 1') 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ГеоргийБыков что не так?